# A journey from akka-stream to fs2 - how to define an akka-stream http flow like stage in fs2 using http4s

Tags: scala, http4s, fs2

i'm on my journey to deepen my knowledge in fs2, and want to try fs2-kafka for a use case where i would replace akka stream. The idea is simple, read from kafka and post data via http request to a sink, then commit back to kafka  on  success. So far i can't really figure out the http part. In akka stream / akka http you have out of the box a flow for that https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-http/current/client-side/host-level.html#using-a-host-connection-pool

```
Flow[(HttpRequest, T), (Try[HttpResponse], T), HostConnectionPool]
```

Which integrate flawlessly with akka stream.

I was trying to see if i could do something similar with http4s and fs2 .

Does anyone has any reference, code sample, blog and what not that shows how to do that kind of integration. So far the only thing i could think of was, wrapping the the stream into the use method of the client resource i.e

```
BlazeClientBuilder[IO](IORuntime.global.compute).resource.use { ..... run stream here ..... }
```

Even then i am not sure of the entire thing

Comment: `someStrem.evalMap(data => sendHttpRequest(someClient, data))` - Where `someClient` was created like `Stream.resource(SomeClientBuilder....build).flatMap { someClient => ??? }`? Or what was the question? how to create the client? how to do the http request?

Comment: I think you answered my question almost. I was  looking for confirmation that i understand well what to do. I have worked with akka stream for a very long time, and as you know they  have massive documentation and ecosys with a lot of example. This is not the case for fs2 or fs2-kafka (in comparison). So that particular use case, is something that one  need to figure out on their own, based on how well you understand the essence of the ecosystem.

Comment: Although i am getting  better with the all cats-effect ecosystem, i'm still learning, and still do not feel  confident 100%. So i am looking for ready  made example, like what you have in akka documentation to confirm that i am going the right way

Comment: So the question was, how do you create the client, and use it in your stream to actually send data that you  consume from  Kafka  ? Can you provide a complete line of the  basic idea, i will  then figure out everything else after that. Thanks

Comment: But i  think i  can  already work with what  you provided :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing with the **typelevel** ecosystem is that everything is just a library, you don't need examples on how many of them interact together, you just need to understand how each library works and the basic rules of composition.

```scala
def createClient(/** whatever arguments you need */): Resource[IO, Client[IO]] = {
  // Fill this based on the documentation of the client of your choice:
  // I would recommend the ember client from http4s:
  // https://http4s.org/v0.23/api/org/http4s/ember/client/emberclientbuilder 
}


def sendHttpRequest(client: Client[IO])(data: Data): IO[Result] = {
  // Fill this based on the documentation of your client:
  // https://http4s.org/v0.23/client/
  // https://http4s.org/v0.23/api/org/http4s/client/client
}

def getStreamOfRecords(/** whatever arguments you need */): Stream[IO, CommittableConsumerRecord[IO, Key, Data]] = {
  // Fill this based on the documentation of fs2-kafka:
  // https://fd4s.github.io/fs2-kafka/docs/consumers
}

def program(/** whatever arguments you need */): Stream[IO, Unit] = {
  // Based on the documentation of fs2 and fs2-kafka I would guess something like this:
  Stream.fromResource(createClient(...)).flatMap { client =>
    getStreamOfRecords(...).evalMapFilter { committable =>
      sendHttpRequest(client)(data = committable.record).map { result =>
        if (result.isSuccess) Some(committable.offset)
        else None
      }
    }.through(commitBatchWithin(...))
  }
}

object Main extends IOApp.Simple {
  override final val run: IO[Unit] =
    program(...).compile.drain
}
```

Note that I wrote all this on top of my head and with just a quick glimpse of the documentation, you need to change many things *(especially types, like `Data` & `Result`)*. As well as tunning things like error handling and when to commit back to **Kafka**.
However, I expect this helps you to get an idea of how to structure your code.

Comment: Thank you so much for this. It helped :)